# Find the minimum and maximum value of a rational function

Tags: inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive numbers. Find the  range of $$\frac{x+1}{xy+x+1}+\frac{y+1}{zy+y+1}+\frac{z+1}{zx+z+1}$$

I think some kind of inequality and a manipulation is possible to arrive at the answer.

Comment: and what Kind of numbers are $x,y,z$?

Comment: What restrictions are there on $x$, $y$ and $z$? If $xy+x+1=0$, etc, then the expression is undefined.

Comment: You should include what you have attempted so far.  Further as others have asked, are there any conditions on $x, y, z$ (assuming they are real numbers)?  For e.g. can they be negative?

Comment: $x,y,z$ are real numbers. I need to solve it without use of multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you intended the restriction $x,y,z > 0$, each of the three summands is positive and less than $1$.

It follows that the range of the sum is a subset of the interval $(0,3)$.

But using $x=y=z$, the sum is
$$\frac{3(x+1)}{x^2+x+1}$$
which approaches $0$ as $x \to \infty$, and approaches $3$ as $x \to 0^{+}$.

By continuity, it follows that the range of the sum is $(0,3)$.

If $x,y,z$ are unrestricted, then using $x=y=1$, the sum approaches $-\infty$ as $z \to {-2}^{-}$, and approaches $+\infty$ as $z \to {-2}^{+}$.

Comment: OK - I missed your argument for each term being $< 1$.  +1